AmbiguousResolutionException in Quarkus with custom MongoClient
I have a problem with bean injections in Quarkus, for MongoClient.
I need a custom MongoClient with a custom Codec:
@ApplicationScoped
public class MongoClientProducer {

    String connectionString = "mongodb+srv://...";

    @Produces
    @MongoClientName("customClient")
    public MongoClient createMongoClient() {
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new CustomCodec()),
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry()
        );

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }
}

Then I use it:
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService implements SomeInterface{


    @Inject
    @MongoClientName("customClient")
    MongoClient customMongoClient;

    ...
}

And I get the following error:
jakarta.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: Ambiguous dependencies for type com.mongodb.client.MongoClient and qualifiers [@MongoClientName("customClient")]s>
        - injection target: com.myproject.MyService#customMongoClient
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.myproject.SomeInterface, java.lang.Object, com.myproject.MyService], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.myproject.MyService]
        - available beans:
                - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.lang.AutoCloseable, com.mongodb.client.MongoClient, java.io.Closeable, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Any, @MongoClientName("customClient")], target=com.mongodb.client.MongoClient createMongoClient(), declaringBean=ccom.myproject.MongoClientProducer]
                - SYNTHETIC bean [types=[com.mongodb.client.MongoClient, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Any, @Named("customClient"), @io.quarkus.mongodb.MongoClientName("customClient")], target=n/a]

I don't understand why I got twice the bean with MongoClientName("customClient"), in producer and synthetic.
I expect having only a single bean for my MongoClient.
I've tried to remove my mongo dependancies in the pom.xml, to see some of theme were redundant.

The reason you are seeing this is because Quarkus already provides such a bean. Is there a reason you want to override it?

Yes, I need to setup a specific Codec in the MongoClient. I don't think my custom client collides with the default one, because the ambiguous dependancy is also about the qualifier I set on my custom client. Or maybe I don't understand well the error message?.

Okay, do you perhaps have a sample application I can try which exhibits the problem in question?
